# Solana Anchor framework: Can't connect to localhost and therefor not deply to it

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, solana-cli, anchor-solana

Anchor deploy
Deploying workspace: http://localhost:8899
Upgrade authority: /home/tomcatzy/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "basic-1"...
Program path: /home/tomcatzy/projects/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/target/deploy/basic_1.so...
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

solana config set --url http://localhost:8899 (Is this enough to start the localhost ?)
solana-keygen new
solana-test-validator

It seems strange that after a succesful anchor build that i can't do a anchor deploy with the solana command lines ran above.
If by any means 'need' to run a - npm init - then where to do it ?[image: trying to deploy a workspace to a localhost]

solana config set --url http://localhost:8899 (Is this enough to start the localhost ?)
solana-keygen new
solana-test-validator

I tried the above and got generated a keypair: keyname_1-keypair.json. The build went succesful but the deploy not !

I'm wondering why not ?

Hopefully some can guide me what to get it succed...

Answer (score 1):

In a separate window / terminal, you need to run `solana-test-validator` so that the tools can talk to your local network.  The error you're seeing on deployment is due to an error on connecting to that network.

Comment: sudo $(command -v solana-sys-tuner) --user $(whoami) > sys-tuner.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 1):

[image]

By following the Solana docs and doing this

```sh
sudo $(command -v solana-sys-tuner) --user $(whoami) > sys-tuner.log 2>&1 &
```

https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#system-tuning

The `test-ledger` folder is done and a `sys-tuner.log` file is created but it's 0 bytes...

[image]

Then i run the `solana-test-validator`  in a separate terminal and the other solana config commands in another termianl then i get the following results ->

[image: Results of trying to get solana-test-validator to run]

Answer (score -2):

You can deploy on-chain programs with the Solana tools.
To deploy a program, you will need the location of the program's shared object.
It will return when you run `anchor build` in the command line.
Run `solana program deploy <PROGRAM_FILEPATH>`.
Successful deployment will return the program id of your program.